# PHP echo styling

Tags: php, styling

I want to make a styling for this PHP Code like this Image:

```
    <?php

function get_ip() {
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

    }
    else {
        return (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '');
    }       
}
$ip=get_ip();
$query=@unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {
    echo "ISP:".$query['isp']."<br/>";
    echo "COUNTRY:".$query['country']."<br/>";
    echo "COUNTRY CODE:".$query['countryCode']."<br/>";
    echo "REGION NAME:".$query['regionName']."<br/>";
    echo "CITY:".$query['city']."<br/>";
    echo "ZIP:".$query['zip']."<br/>";
    echo "LATITUDE:".$query['latitude']."<br/>";
    echo "LONGITUDE:".$query['longitude']."<br/>";
    echo "TIMEZONE:".$query['timezone']."<br/>";
    echo "ORG:".$query['org']."<br/>";
    echo "AS:".$query['as']."<br/>";
}

?>
```

and I want the results like this Image:

[image]

Comment: Use HTML and CSS for styling.

Comment: Put it in an HTML table, and use CSS to add styling.

Comment: Can you help me